# surface area and volume of a spherical cap

Tags: geometry, area, volume, derivation-of-formulae

While researching the formulas for these calculations, I am completely stumped by how the ones circled in red are derived.  I think the surface area formula is wrong here since that's the formula for the surface area of the label of a cylinder.
Does anyone know the correct formula, or if that is the correct formula, why it is the correct formula?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both can be derived using some basic integral calculus. Take into account that the equation of a circle of radius r is $y=\sqrt{r^2-x^2}$, thus $y'=\frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$. So
\begin{align*}
  V_s&=\int_{r-h}^r\pi(\sqrt{r^2-x^2})^2dx=\pi\int_{r-h}^rr^2-x^2dx\\
  A_s&=\int_{r-h}^r2\pi\sqrt{r^2-x^2}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\right)^2}dx
\end{align*}
To see how these formulas are derived you can check any clasical calculus book as could be [Stewart's](https://www.stewartcalculus.com) or [Thomas's](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134438981). Feel free to reply if you need help when computing any of those integrals.

Now, if you want to avoid Calculus, use [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle), i will ilustrate how to use it to proof the volume of half the sphere, a restriction to my argument shall yield the formula you are looking for:

If you consider a sphere of radius $r$ when you consider the transversal section a distance $s$ away from the center it has area $A_T=\pi r^2-\pi s^2$; which can be seen as the area of a circle of radius $r$ minus the area of a circle with radius $s$. Now consider a cilinder whose base's radius is $r$ and with height $r$ without a cone of base $r$ and height $r$ as in the image.
[image]

By Cavalieri's principle this shape has the same volume as half sphere and it is clearly $$V=\pi(r^2)r-\frac{1}{3}\pi r^2r=\frac{2}{3}r^3$$ To deal with your problem consider calculating only a part of the volume of the image instead of all.

I hope it is useful

Comment: Thanks for the above help.  Is there any way to derive the formula without Calculus, just with geometry and trig?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a non-calculus aproach

Answer (score 2):

The formula for the cap surface area $S=2\pi rh$
is indeed correct, which can be derived via the double integral of the surface element $ds = r^2\sin\theta \ d\theta d\phi $ in spherical coordinates, i.e.

$$S =\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\cos^{-1}\frac{r-h}r}r^2\sin\theta \ d\theta d\phi=2\pi rh
$$